# How to make the text-to-video generation keep some components the same throughout the video?

Tags: prompt-design, text-to-video

I generated this below video from [this website](https://replicate.com/lucataco/animate-diff) and converted it into a gif file and attached here.

I would like to ask for a solution that can keep the armor and the headwear the same throughout the video. Right now, they are changing constantly. Some frames are acceptable, some are not. I don't really want any style of the components specifically. I just want them to be consistent.

**Prompt**

> high quality, 1 girl, solo, anime, holy, knight, plate armor, wings, holding sword

**Result**

[image: result from text-to-img generation]

How to make the text-to-video generation keep some components the same throughout the video?

Answer (score 1):

> How to make the text-to-video generation keep some components the same throughout the video?

Keeping some components the same throughout the video is referred to as  temporal consistency. Temporal consistency is one of the key challenges in video generation. There are many papers on it, e.g. [Temporally Consistent Transformers for Video Generation](https://wilson1yan.github.io/teco/) and [MoStGAN-V: Video Generation with Temporal Motion Styles](https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.02777).